# Even numbers in base 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

We all know even numbers are the ones that end in even digits. How do we analyze even numbers  in base 2?

Comment: Note: Even numbers are of the form $2k$ for $k$ an integer. How does multiplying by 2 work in base 2? (Note well that 2 is $(10)_2$ in base 2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Look at the last (least significant) digit.

Remember, if $n=(b_mb_{m-1}\dots b_1b_0)_{\text{two}}$, so that the binary digits from left to right are $b_m,\dots,b_0$, then

$$n=\sum_{k=0}^mb_k2^k=2^mb_m+2^{m-1}b_{m-1}+\ldots+2b_1+b_0\;.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if it ends in $0$, it is even and if it ends in $1$ it is odd, right?

Comment: @Gigili: You’ve got it.